# Finding multiple values with STRPOS in PHP to filter

Tags: php

The following foreach outputs a list of dates, however I do not want to display any that have a Saturday or a Sunday in the output. What I've got removes any output containing Saturday but I can't seem to remove the Sunday, I've tried using the or || in various places but with no luck.
I'm formatting the date into this format - 'Monday 9 December 2019'

```
foreach($data['Appointments'] as $dates)
    $readabledate = date("l j F Y ",strtotime(date($dates['Starttime'])));

    if (strpos($readabledate, 'Saturday') === false) {  
    echo $readabledate; //lists all dates
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use &&, both results have to be false. One will always be true.

```
<?php

$data['Appointments'][] = array('Starttime' => "2019-12-06");
$data['Appointments'][] = array('Starttime' => "2019-12-07");
$data['Appointments'][] = array('Starttime' => "2019-12-08");
$data['Appointments'][] = array('Starttime' => "2019-12-09");


foreach($data['Appointments'] as $dates){
    $readabledate = date("l j F Y ",strtotime(date($dates['Starttime'])));

    if (strpos($readabledate, 'Saturday') === FALSE && strpos($readabledate, 'Sunday') === FALSE ) {  
    echo $readabledate . "\n"; //lists all dates
    }

}
```